# ¿Como obtener máxima sumatoria de n elementos de un array?

Tags: java, algoritmos, optimización

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public int sumaMax(int[] a) {
    int maxSuma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < a.length; j++) {
            int suma = 0;
            for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
                suma += a[k];
                if (suma > maxSuma) {
                    maxSuma = suma;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return maxSuma;
}
```

Básicamente lo que quiero que este código haga es coger un arreglo que posee N números enteros y **encuentre las n celdas consecutivas cuya suma sea el valor más grande**.

Ejemplo 1, tengo un arreglo con los valores `{-3, 2, 3, 1, -2}` y con el código me retorna la suma de `2 + 3 + 1 = 6` ya que coge los datos consecutivos y obtiene la suma más grande que puede existir.

Ejemplo 2, tengo un arreglo con los valores `{-3, 2, 3, 1, -2, 9}`, en este caso solo me retorna el número `9` debido a que es el dato más grande y no lo podemos sumar con el que está en el lado izquierdo ya que nos daría `7` y sería menor que `9`.

Entonces la cuestión es la siguiente, hay 3 `for` anidados por lo tanto es lento.

**Mi pregunta es si existe alguna forma de optimizarlo.**

Comment: Si todos son enteros positivos con el "i=0" hasta el "a.length"; si hay negativos  y positivos, eliminando primero los negativos y solo sumando positivos, si solo hay negativos, pues buscar el negativo más cercano a cero. Salvo ejemplo tengas dos veces "-2" y una vez "-3" y así por el estilo.

Comment: Hola @Emma , No está clara tu preguntad dado que el valor devuelto por tu algoritmo `sumaMax` **siempre será la suma de todos los elementos.**   , sería bueno que mostraras mediante un ejemplo el resultado esperado con una entrada conocida `(array)`

Comment: Al decir: _"encuentre las n celdas consecutivas cuya suma sea el valor más grande"_, **dime el por qué no puede sumarse** `(-3) + 2 + 3 + 1 + (-2) + 9` si son consecutivas y su suma es `10` y es mayor que `9`.

Comment: Continuando el comentario de @Davlio, ¿el resultado no debería ser `13`? `2 + 3 + 1 + (-2) + 9`

Comment: Por cierto, si maxSuma lo inicializas a 0, en caso de matrices de solo negativos, el resultado será erróneamente 0 en vez del negativo mayor.
Aparte de eso, y de que el resultado correcto según tu problema es 13, no veo que se pueda optimizar mucho mas...

Answer (score 1):

Sí. Es posible modificar/simplificar el algoritmo de modo que solo necesitas un bucle:

```
public int sumaMax(int[] a) {
    int suma = a[0];
    int max = suma;

    for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        suma = suma <= 0 ? a[i] : suma + a[i];

        if (suma > max) {
            max = suma;
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/QIRJA36650)</kbd>

El algoritmo es simplemente de ir sumando los números uno por uno e ir verificando a cada iteración si hemos alcanzado un nuevo máximo.

Sin embargo, la parte clave del algoritmo es que, si durante una iteración nos damos cuenta que la suma que llevamos acumulado hasta ese punto ha caído en cero o bajo cero, entonces ignoramos todos los números que hemos sumado hasta ese punto, y comenzamos una nueva suma.

Obviamente, el algoritmo es más eficiente que el que tienes, ya que solo necesita iterar la lista una sola vez. Es más, también maneja mejor listas con números negativos.  Por ejemplo, si la lista es `{-3, -2, -5}`, mi algoritmo devuelve `-2`, mientras que el tuyo devuelve `0`.

Y contrario a lo que describes en la pregunta, para la lista `{-3, 2, 3, 1, -2, 9}`, el resultado correcto debería ser `13` (`2, 3, 1, -2, 9`), no `9`.  Interesantemente, aunque dijistes que el resultado debería ser `9` en ese caso, tu propio algoritmo devuelve `13` correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es recorrer tu arreglo y entre el total de ellas sumar los valores quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public int sumaMax(int[] a)
{
    int maxSuma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        maxSuma+=a[i];
    }
    return maxSuma;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Un código para hacer esto:

> coger un arreglo que posee N números enteros y encuentre las n celdas consecutivas cuya suma sea el valor más grande.

es como el siguiente:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {

    public static final String EXMESSAGE = "n debe ser mayor que 0 y menor que el largo del arreglo";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] testData = {
            {7, 95, 22, 31, 75, 41, 78, 36, 92, 63},
            {3, 90, 42, 39, 19, 84, 85, 76, 7, 8},
            {75, 64, 17, 94, 63, 52, 9, 30, 73, 22},
            {62, 28, 54, 99, 50, 24, 55, 2, 53, 47},
            {78, 47, 71, 85, 75, 46, 68, 79, 72, 13},
            {22, 20, 28, 71, 17, 98, 33, 36, 90, 10},
            {31, 77, 57, 8, 45, 97, 48, 95, 23, 33},
            {2, 76, 74, 13, 68, 55, 21, 26, 82, 57},
            {16, 13, 36, 67, 27, 67, 28, 88, 8, 23},
            {52, 33, 76, 98, 90, 67, 53, 11, 9, 22}
        };

        for (int[] arreglo : testData) {
            System.out.println("Test: ");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arreglo));
            System.out.println(sumaMax(arreglo, 4) + "\n");
        }
    }

    static public int sumaMax(int[] a, int n) {
        // validar n
        if (n < 1 || n > a.length) {
             throw new RuntimeException(EXMESSAGE);
        }

        int maxSuma = 0;
        // int index = 0;

        // sumar los n primeros
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            maxSuma += a[i];
        }

        // buscar la maxima suma consecutiva
        for (int i = n, suma = maxSuma; i < a.length; i++) {
            suma += a[i] - a[i - n];

            if (suma > maxSuma) {
                maxSuma = suma;
                //index = i - n + 1;
            }
        }

        //System.out.println("inicio del max:" + index + " valor:" + a[index]);
        return maxSuma;
    }
}
```

El parámetro *n* de la función es la cantidad de consecutivos, pero este valor se debe escoger de forma manual. Este algoritmo no toma solo los positivos.

**Ejemplos:**

```
sumaMax(arreglo, 10) // n = 10
[52, 33, 76, 98, 90, 67, 53, 11, 9, 22]
```

Esto dará como resultado **511**, o sea la suma de todos los elementos (*length = n*).

```
sumaMax(arreglo, 1) // n = 10
[52, 33, 76, 98, 90, 67, 53, 11, 9, 22]
```

Dará como resultado **98**, ya que es el mayor de una serie de 1 consecutivos.

**PD:** Si descomentas las 3 lineas de código puedes imprimir la posición donde comienza la mayor suma. :P